# MYSQLCC Connection Error

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error message after installing MYSQLCC on my laptop.

[root@localhost:3306] ERROR 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Why is this error popping up, and can I have a solution to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you haven't started the MySQL service on the laptop.

Comment: a) mysql isn't running b) mysql isn't running at the spot mysqlcc is looking for it c) you haven't installed mysql at all.

Comment: @Barmar How do I start the MySQL service?

Comment: I don't know. Have you even installed it? If you're running windows, I'd expect the explanation to be in the WAMP documentation.

Comment: @Barmar I'm new to this, and I honestly don't have a clue :( However, I did try to tweak it, but to no avail

Comment: MYSQLCC is a control application for the MySQL server. It presumes that you're already running a MySQL server.